# Does sieve's version of regex allow me to look for Cyrillic or CJK characters?

Tags: regex, unicode, cjk, cyrillic, sieve-language

I'm slowly fine-tuning my sieve filter. I noticed I was getting a lot of spam in Russian, so I thought I could filter on the presence of Cyrillic in the subject. I thought maybe three consecutive characters would be a good test, and it seems to work pretty well. Here's the line:

`elsif header :regex "Subject" [ "[а-яА-Я]{3,}" ]`

It's not ideal, because there are plenty of Cyrillic characters outside the *А-Я* range. Also, I'd like to do the same with CJK characters, and I'm not sure even how to begin with those.

Is it possible in sieve to specify a script as a character class? I've done it before in other regex implementations, but it seems to me that it's handled differently, if at all, by different regex flavours.

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Try `[\p{Cyrillic}\p{Han}]{3}`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you, this is exactly what I'm looking for. I couldn't seem to find documentation for this anywhere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
[\p{Cyrillic}\p{Han}]{3}
```

*Details*:

- `[` - start of a character class

  - `\p{Cyrillic}` - any Cyrillic char
  - `\p{Han}` - any Chinese char
- `]{3}` - end of the character class, three repetitions.